# how to return a specific status code in Kotlin

Tags: spring-boot, rest, kotlin

I've set up a route that when I get a name in my post body I will search the DB and return an ID value.

What I want to do is once there is no ID present in the DB return a 204 status code.

But should that be handled in the service or in my controller?

and

How do I return my specific status code?

```
 @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    @PostMapping("/ID_values/")
    fun getID(
        @RequestBody
        name: String
    ): ResponseEntity<String> = ResponseEntity.ok(IDLookupService.lookupIDValue(name))
}

@Service
class EmailLookupService(
    private val IDRepo: IDRepo
) : Logging {
    fun lookupIDValue(name: String): String {
        val IDLookupResult = IDRepo.findById(name)
        return if (IDLookupResult.isPresent) {
            IDLookupResult.get().ID.toString()
        } else {
            // return status code 204
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It should be in the service layer.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should omit the `@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)` annotation if you do not wish to always return a status code of 200. Using that annotation, it would suffice to only specify the response body as return value (i.e specify return type `String` and then return only `result` in your example), and Spring would automatically wrap that into a response entity with HTTP-status OK.

Second, you need some way to tell the caller of `IDLookupService.lookupIDValue` (which should probably be called on an instance of `IDLookupService` and not the class itself) that there was nothing found. This could be done for instance by changing the return type to `String?` and return `null` if nothing was found.

Then you can change `getID` to return

```
val result = idLookupService.lookupIDValue(name)
return if(result != null) ResponseEntity.ok(result) 
else ResponseEntity("not found", HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
```

If you wish to return something different than a `String` in the case there was nothing found (like an error object with detailed information; in the example here it is simply the text `"not found"`), you can change the response type of `getID` to `ResponseEntity<*>`.